# onclick() with multiple function only execute the first

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I'm trying to execute two functions but it only execute the first one. I think that when I change a HTML variable value, the javascript stops its execution.

This is the code that I'm executing:
HTML:

```
<div class="funcion" onclick="country_function();setGeo(1)">
```

JavaScript:

```
function country_function(){        
        region_hide();
        class_hide();
        country_show();
    };

function country_show(){
        var popup = document.getElementById("countrypopmenu");
        popup.classList.toggle("show");
    };
    function country_hide(){
        var popup = document.getElementById("countrypopmenu");
        popup.classList.toggle("hidden");
    };
    function region_show(){
        var popup = document.getElementById("regionpopmenu");
        popup.classList.toggle("show");
    };
    function region_hide(){
        var popup = document.getElementById("regionpopmenu");
        popup.classList.toggle("hidden");
    };
    function class_show(){
        var popup = document.getElementById("classpopmenu");
        popup.classList.toggle("show");
    };
    function class_hide(){
        var popup = document.getElementById("classpopmenu");
        popup.classList.toggle("hidden");
    };

    function setGeo(geoVal) {
      document.getElementByID('geodata').value= geoVal;
      window.alert(geoVal);
    };
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't execute all the functions?

Comment: Can you elaborate which functions are executing and which not?

Comment: region_hide();class_hide();country_show() and setGeo()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `setGeo`, you've mis-capitalized `.getElementById()`.

But, beyond that, you have a ton of code that is not-needed and a solution that is brittle and won't scale as your needs change.

You really just need one function that takes two arguments - what element to show/hide/toggle and what operation to perform on it (show/hide/toggle).

Additionally, the practice of setting up event handlers via HTML event attributes is a 25+ year old technique that dates back to before there were web standards and **[there are many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)** not to use this ancient technique today. Separate your JavaScript from your HTML completely and use modern standards for event configurations.

```js
// Get your DOM references 
var f = document.querySelector(".function");
var c = document.querySelector(".country");
var r = document.querySelector(".region");
var l = document.querySelector(".locale");

// Set up your event handlers in JavaScript, not HTML
f.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Just call the single function as many times as needed
  // with the appropriate arguments each time:
  showHideToggle(c,"show");
  showHideToggle(r,"hide");
  showHideToggle(l,"toggle");
});

// One function to do all operations
function showHideToggle(element, operation){
 // For show/hide/toggle operations just do the right
 // thing with the "hidden" class. 
 switch (operation.toLowerCase()) {
   case "show":
     element.classList.remove("hidden");
     break;
   case "hide":
     element.classList.add("hidden");
     break;
   default:
     element.classList.toggle("hidden");
     break;      
 }
}
```

```css
div { opacity:1; transition:all 1s;  }
.function { cursor:pointer; user-select:none; margin:1em; }
.hidden { opacity:0; }
```

```html
<div class="function">Click Me</div>
<div class="country hidden">Country</div>
<div class="region">Region</div>
<div class="locale hidden">Locale</div>
```

Comment: Ay muchisimas gracias

Comment: @RobertaGimenez De nada,

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in function satGeo :

```
 document.getElementById('geodata').value= geoVal;
```

```js
function country_function(){        
        console.log("Inside function 1");
    };

  function setGeo(geoVal) {
    console.log("inside function 2");
  };
```

```html
<div class="funcionff" onclick="country_function();setGeo(1);">click</div>
```

Comment: so, to be clear @RobertaGimenez in the console, you do NOT see and error? `document.getElementByID is not a function`?

Comment: I'm not using a console so I only know that the value is not changing. I'm working in an app in my localhost

Comment: What kind of monsters will debug without a console?

Comment: HELP ME PLEASE.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to only attach one function to `onclick` attribute, then execute as many functions as needed in that event handler.

For example:

`<div class="function" onclick="onFunctionButtonClick()"></div>`

```
function onFunctionButtonClick () {
  region_hide();
  class_hide();
  country_show();
  setGeo(1);
}
```

Or even put the listener logic in JavaScript, so you can keep your HTML away from main application logic and have cleaner HTML.

`<div class="function"></div>`

```
var functionButton = document.getElementsByClassName('function')[0];
functionButton.addEventListener('click', onFunctionButtonClick);
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName()` scans the entire document for all matching nodes, so it doesn't make sense to immediately throw out all but the first one after doing that. Additionally, it returns a "live" node list, which impedes performance. `.querySelector()` is what you want.